# Mathematical rebus: $x^2+15600=649x$

Tags: mathematics, rebus, knowledge

Which name of a large American city does the following equation represent?

$$
x^2+15600=649x
$$

Comment: Weird that the answer gets more up-votes than the asker.

Comment: @ghosts I don't find it that surprising, given that it's a pretty dumb riddle with only one posted solution.  I'm actually surprised that I got this many upvotes!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The city you are referring to is

> Chicago
> Solving the quadratic equation gives us $x = 25$ or $x = 624$. Or to put it another way, it's ['25 or 6 to 4'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/25_or_6_to_4), a song by the band Chicago.

Comment: To the creator, may I suggest rephrasing the riddle to, "what name of a large American city do the roots of this equation represent"?  The answer above doesn't involve *solving* the equation, but rather finding its roots. To say that the entire equation describes a name is a bit generous.

Comment: @bcf I thought about that, but 1) In this case you *are* actually finding the *solution to an equation* (which are the *roots of the polynomial* $x^2-649x+15600$), and 2) I thought that it would make an already simple puzzle *way* too easy.